# I want to override authenticate_user and current_user method of devise gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I want to override authenticate_user! and current_user method of devise gem in my application Controller can you please help me with regards to that
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may be able to monkey-patch it like:

```
module Devise
  module Controllers
    module Helpers
      def authenticate_user!
        #do some stuff
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I would ask what the ultimate goal is, because Devise has some customizability built into it already, and overriding these methods makes me wonder "why use Devise at all?"

Comment: This is a requirement from management. So i have to follow. i want to do LDAP and Database Authentication both together than default Devise behavior do this job for me..

Comment: Hi, but where to put this file? In which directory? And, is the same to write custom method in `application_controller.rb`? Thanks!

Comment: You can put it anywhere that gets loaded. I would suggest maybe in `application_helper.rb` since it overrides a helper method. But you could put it where you mention as well.

Answer (score 9):

On overriding how a user is authenticated:

Devise uses Warden under the hood
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb

So you can just add a new strategy in Warden to authenticate your users. See
https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Strategies

You should not need to override current_user. What challenge are you facing ?
Do you need a different model returned ?

Comment: Monica, why would someone return a different model? I'm guessing it would be if you had something like a User (tied to Devise) and a Profile (with all the human-readable info about the user). If that's the case, how would one go about doing that?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to *add* code to `authenticate_user!`

```
class DuckController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_duck

  ...

  private

  def authenticate_duck
    #use Devise's method
    authenticate_user!
    #add your own stuff
    unless current_user.duck.approved?
      flash[:alert] = "Your duck is still pending. Please contact support for support."
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It does not work. after authenticate_user! method it retrurns from the method and the code after that not executes.

Answer (score 6):

You have to create a custom class to override the default Devise behavior:

```
  class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
    def redirect_url
      #return super unless [:worker, :employer, :user].include?(scope) #make it specific to a scope
       new_user_session_url(:subdomain => 'secure')
    end

    # You need to override respond to eliminate recall
    def respond
      if http_auth?
        http_auth
      else
        redirect
      end
    end
  end
```

And in your config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
  end
```

But I suggest check out the Devise documentation :)

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated

Answer (score 1):

At `application_controller.rb` you can overwrite just as you want:

```
def authenticate_user!
  super # just if want the default behavior 
  call_a_method_to_something if current_user
  # or
  call_a_method_to_something if current_user.nil?
end
```