# Add filter after devise's :authenticate_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, namespaces

I want to add a second filter after `:authenticate_user!`.

Currently, I have a typical setup in my base namespaced controller:

```ruby
module Admin
  class AdminController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
  end
end
```

But any variation on this, doesn't work: the redirect doesn't happen so the user still gets access when she shouldn't.

```ruby
# Doesn't work
before_filter :admin_only
def admin_only
  :authenticate_user!
end

# Doesn't work
before_filter do
  :authenticate_user!
end

# Doesn't work
before_filter [:authenticate_user!]
```

If any of these variations would work, I could add my extra filtering code. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just append your extra before filter method

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :my_extra_before_filter_method
```

`authenticate_user!` will be executed first, followed by your custom filter

UPDATE: you can also call `before_filter` twice

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
before_filter :my_extra_before_filter_method
```

Comment: The "joy" of ruby: a million ways to do the same thing, but only one way is right.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7747912/1157) to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425231/i-want-to-override-authenticate-user-and-current-user-method-of-devise-gem) says the following:

> *Devise uses Warden under the hood*
>   https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb
>
> *So you can just add a new strategy in Warden to authenticate your users. See* https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Strategies

**Do you want to add a second filter? Or maybe just override?**