# Modyfying before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise

I have an `admin:boolean` field in my user model, and would like to be able to to check in my controller if the user is an admin before they can edit anything.

How would I modify `before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit]` to check if the user is an admin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to override authenticate\_user and current\_user method of devise gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425231/i-want-to-override-authenticate-user-and-current-user-method-of-devise-gem)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add another before action that will be called after authenticate_user! to check if current user has admin privilege.

```
class YourController
  # first call authenticate_user! to check if user is signed in
  before_action authenticate_user!, only: [:edit]
  # if user is signed (current_user exist), check if he is admin
  before_action authenticate_admin!, only: [:edit]

  def authenticate_admin!
    # check if current user is admin
    unless current_user.admin
      # if current_user is not admin redirect to some route
      redirect_to 'some_public_route'
    end
    # if current_user is admin he will proceed to edit action
  end
end
```