# Custom authenticate_user! devise method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a boolean attribute 'boss' on my user model, how do I create a custom `authenticate_user!` in my before_filter so that only users where `user.boss == true` are authenticated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425231/i-want-to-override-authenticate-user-and-current-user-method-of-devise-gem

Comment: and for the requirement you are saying you should override session controller of devise gem instead authenticate_user!

Answer (score -2):

```
before_filter do 
    redirect_to root_path unless current_user && current_user.boss?
end
```