# How to enable guest account for a specific controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm stuck with an implementation for a project I'm working on. Using rails 7 with devise, all users can sign in so I have the methods `authenticate_user!` and `current_user`, which, again, works fine.

I've introduced a `Customer` model. For now, I do not want the customer to register with password etc, I want them to click a link, sent to them from my application, then visit a page:

```rb
# Observer

class CustomerObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_create(customer)
    secret_param = customer.to_sgid(expires_in: nil).to_s
    url = ENV['HOST'] + "?csig=#{secret_param}"

    # Send email with the url...
  end
end
```

Once customer clicks that link, they should be taken to a special page and should have access to this controller only.

Been looking at [GlobalID](https://github.com/rails/globalid) and not sure how to use the `for: name` in `.to_sgid` so that I could restrict the customer to access only the `CustomersController` and the `show` action.

In all controllers I have `before_action :authenticate_user!`. First thing came to mine is [overriding that method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425231/i-want-to-override-authenticate-user-and-current-user-method-of-devise-gem). Feels wrong. How to have a customer access the `CustomersController` via the signed link and still be protected from unauthorize users?

I'm currently exploring [this method](https://gorails.com/forum/devise-with-multiple-user-models-with-single-login-form) where I could potentially have the customer model authenticatable? This means having two logins, one for `user` and other for `customer`. Would be nice to have one sign in path `/sign_in/` for both `user` and `customer`. I feel this post is changing its direction.

Comment: Have you ever used Pundit? Or CanCan?

Comment: No. Does either works with Devise?

Comment: Yes! I use Pundit all the time with Devise, but CanCan is popular too. Devise is for authentication, they are for authorization.

Answer (score 0):

How about some lazy check like this;

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, :if => :check_csig

# ...
private

def check_csig
  # if csig param do not exists, call the authenticate_user!
  true unless params[:csig].exists?

  # if csig param exists and csig is valid do not call the authenticate_user!
  false if check_csig
  true
end
```

OR

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, :except =>  [:csgi]
before_action :check_csgi,         :only   =>  [:csgi]

# ...
private

def check_csig
  #check if csgi is valid
end
```

Comment: I feel I may have issues with this approach in the future. It would be best to have something I could use globally. What if I wanted to extend access to another controller? See what I'm saying?

Comment: So you better use something like thisbefore_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:csgi_method]